# Configure multiple websites on a single magento install

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, configuration, multidomain

I am using XAMPP and Magento 1.9.2.
I have created a website store and store view in the Magento admin panel.

How do I access it? The way I access the main *Store => localhost/magento*. 
I have changed the base URL of the default config so I cannot access Magento admin now.

What are the steps to do that?

Comment: Have you specified a secure and unsecure url for you alt store?

Comment: What do i add in the base url

Comment: For bothsecured and unsecured

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-multiple-stores-websites-with-one-magento-installation-on-different-domains/

http://creativsite.com/newsroom/2014/06/magento-multistore-setup-on-localhost/

Answer (score 1):

Please check this guide it should help you to setup your local environment:
https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains